# How to add an Internet Explorer Behaviour file (.htc) from a different domain?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm redesigning my Tumblr blog and I use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to add some eye-candy to Internet Explorer. The problem with this is that CSS3 Pie uses Internet Explorer specific files (.htc) that can only be served from the same domain as the HTML file, which is something I can't do on Tumblr.

The thing is that without that file the website breaks on IE6 & IE7 (I'm using HTML5 syntax and apparently these browsers don't really like it even with some help from Modernizr).

So, do you know any ways of adding such files from another domain than the one that serves the HTML? No matter how hacky it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using conditional comments for IE to gracefully alert users their browsers are not supported, or to reformat the content for IE users.

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styleIE6.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styleIE7.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styleIE8.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Another alternative, which I'm guessing is easier than the ".htc" hack you are suggesting. Is to use a basic java-script redirect. If the user is using IE (less than IE9) redirect them to a simplified, IE only, web page.